# Объясните что делает программа?

Tags: c#

Объясните что делает программа?

```
 var result = (from s in readText
                              let elements = s.Split(',')
                              where elements.Count() > 3
                              select elements[2])
                    .Where(dd => !dd.Contains("Jam") && !dd.Contains("Rt"))
                    .GroupBy(el => el)
                    .Select(one => new { CodeValue = one.Key, Count = one.Count() });



foreach (var val in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("код ошибки {0}\t число ошибок: {1}", val.CodeValue, val.Count);

                W.WriteLine("код ошибки {0}\t число ошибок: {1}", val.CodeValue, val.Count);
            }
```

Comment: Ну, вот закрыли :( А я ответ уже написал... http://pastebin.com/U3tYWZK3

Comment: спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из списка строк достаёт содержащие `Jam` и `Rt` фрагменты между второй и третьей запятой (или второй запятой и концом строки) и считает их количество.